# ¿Cómo usar POCOs como intemediaros con cualquier framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Buenas comunidad,

estoy tratando de hacer que mi proyecto no muera por cualquier cambio que yo haga en la bd, uso Entity Framework, la idea es teniendo las debidas clases creadas por Entity framework, tener una intermediaria entre este y el programa. Esto es lo que estoy intentando:

Clase Generada por EF:

```
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    ExpedientePOCO exp = new ExpedientePOCO();
    public Expediente()
    {
        this.Documentos = new HashSet<Documento>();
    }

    public int idExpediente = { get; set; };
    public string NombreExpediente = { get; set; };
    public System.DateTime FechaCreacion = { get; set; };
    public string DuenioExpediente = { get; set; };
    public int CantidadDocumento = { get; set; };

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Documento> Documentos { get; set; }
```

Mi clase POCO:

```
    public Expediente()
    {
        this.Documentos = new HashSet<Documento>();
    }

    public int idExpediente { get; set; }
    public string NombreExpediente { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime FechaCreacion { get; set; }
    public string DuenioExpediente { get; set; }
    public int CantidadDocumento { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Documento> Documentos { get; set; }
```

Sin embargo no he sido capaz de probarlo puesto que no se me ocurre cómo podría interactuar con la bd con esto.

EDIT:

La idea es que la clase POCO, en este caso Expediente, sea la que interactúe entre la capa de presentación y la capa de negocio. Y que la capa de negocio interactue nada más con las entidades poco y la capa de datos de EF. Para independizar la capa de presentación del modelo de datos. Ya logré insertar datos de esta manera. Ahora la pregunta es cómo podría recuperar los datos de esta manera. He intentado esto:

```
public static List<ExpedientePOCO> GetExpedientes()
    {
        Ejercicio2Entities context = new Ejercicio2Entities();
        List<ExpedientePOCO> exp = new List<ExpedientePOCO>();
        using (context)
        {
            try
            {
                exp = context.Expedientes.ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return exp;
       }
    }
```

Pero claramente, los tipos no son lo mismo, unas son POCO's y otras entidades de EF. Se me ocurrió hacer esto:

```
 foreach (var a in exp)
                {
                    expedientePOCO.Add(new ExpedientePOCO { 
                        idExpediente = a.idExpediente,
                        NombreExpediente = a.NombreExpediente,
                        FechaCreacion = a.FechaCreacion,
                        DuenioExpediente = a.DuenioExpediente,
                        CantidadDocumento = a.CantidadDocumento,
                        Documentos = a.Documentos
                                                            });
                }
```

Pero a la hora de querer pasar los Documentos en ese Expediente me dice que no puedo convertir de Modelo.Documentos a Entidades.DocumentoPOCO

Comment: Pudieras darle una checada a AutoMapper
http://automapper.org/

Comment: Puedes explicar con un poco mas de detalle cual es tu problema?

Comment: No es muy clara tu pregunta, pero tal vez lo que estés buscando es el [patrón de Fabricación](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb972258.aspx)

Comment: Ahorita lo edito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno, pues probando, llegué a una conclusion.

Como pueden ver tengo la clase creada por EF y mi clase POCO que es una replica.

En el caso de los expedientes, lo que hice fue convertirlos. Como reflejo en la pregunta, un expediente tiene muchos documentos, lo que hice para convertir todo a un POCO fue:

```
var exp = context.Expedientes.AsNoTracking().Include(x => x.Documentos.Select(s => s.Archivo)).ToList();
                foreach (var entidad in exp)
                {
                    String fecha = String.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyy}", entidad.FechaCreacion);
                    expPOCO.Add(new ExpedientePOCO
                    {
                        idExpediente = entidad.idExpediente,
                        NombreExpediente = entidad.NombreExpediente,
                        FechaCreacion = Convert.ToDateTime(fecha),
                        DuenioExpediente = entidad.DuenioExpediente,
                        CantidadDocumento = entidad.CantidadDocumento
                    });
                    foreach (var expedientePOCO in expPOCO)
                    {
                        foreach (var documentos in entidad.Documentos)
                        {
                            DocumentoPOCO documento = new DocumentoPOCO()
                            {
                                idDocumento = documentos.idDocumento,
                                idExpediente = documentos.idExpediente,
                                NombreDocumento = documentos.NombreDocumento,
                                FechaCreacion = documentos.FechaCreacion,
                                Expedientes = expedientePOCO
                            };
                            expedientePOCO.Documentos.Add(documento);
```

de esta manera, lo que recibe la capa de presentación son propiedades POCO por lo que ahora, puedo trabajar con ellos. Al querer guardar en la base de datos, actualizar o eliminar, sólo hay que hacerlo a la inversa, es decir pasar de propiedades POCO a propiedades EF:

```
Expediente exp = context.Expedientes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.idExpediente == expedientePOCO.idExpediente);
            Expediente expediente = new Expediente();
            if (exp != null)
            {
                expediente = exp;
            }
            else
            {
                expediente.idExpediente = expedientePOCO.idExpediente;
                expediente.NombreExpediente = expedientePOCO.NombreExpediente;
                expediente.FechaCreacion = expedientePOCO.FechaCreacion;
                expediente.DuenioExpediente = expedientePOCO.DuenioExpediente;
                expediente.CantidadDocumento = expedientePOCO.CantidadDocumento;
            }

            foreach (var documentosPOCO in expedientePOCO.Documentos)
            {

                Documento documento = new Documento();
                if(documentosPOCO.idDocumento == 0)
                {
                    documento.idDocumento = documentosPOCO.idDocumento;
                    documento.idExpediente = documentosPOCO.idExpediente;
                    documento.NombreDocumento = documentosPOCO.NombreDocumento;
                    documento.FechaCreacion = documentosPOCO.FechaCreacion;
                    documento.Expediente = expediente;
                }
                else
                {
                    documento = context.Documentos.FirstOrDefault(x => x.idDocumento == documentosPOCO.idDocumento);
                }
                if (documentosPOCO.idDocumento == 0)
                {
                    expediente.Documentos.Add(documento);
                }
                foreach (var archivo in documentosPOCO.Archivos)
                {
                    if (archivo.idArchivo == 0)
                    {
                        documento.Archivo.Add(new Archivo
                        {
                            idArchivo = archivo.idArchivo,
                            idDocumento = archivo.idDocumento,
                            NombreImagen = archivo.NombreImagen,
                            ArchivoImg = archivo.ArchivoImg,
                            Documento = documento
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
```

En ese caso, valido si es un expediente que ya existe o si es uno nuevo. Espero que a alguien le sirva si quiere hacer algo similar.